# Problema cargando una tabla con datos SQL en c#

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

estoy creando una página web y quiero mostrar una tabla con datosguardados de esa misma tabla en un servidor SQL. Por ahora tengo esto:

```
public partial class historyTable : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=NameServer;uid=team;" +
          "pwd=contraseña;database=BaseDeDatos; Initial Catalog=history;Integrated Security=true;");

        cn.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM history", cn);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Estoy intentando mostrar los datos de la tabla "history" pero me pone que tengo un fallo en dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; y dn cn.Close()

Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es el fallo que te muestra? y no veo donde estas abriendo la conexión: `cn.Open()`

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Se me olvido copiar esa linea de cogido antes, también pasé los parámetros de la conección al mismo método. El error que me aparece es: Error CS0103 El nombre 'dataGridView1' no existe en el contexto actual.

Comment: Pues tu error lo que quiere decir que tu `Objeto DataGridView` no tiene este nombre: `dataGridView1` verifica cual es el nombre que tiene el objeto, Selecciona el Objeto en el diseñador, y en las propiedades verifica la propiedad `(name)` y Listo si ese es el único error.

Answer (score 0):

```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("DataSource=/*Aqui*/; Initial Catalog=history;Integrated Security=true;");
```

lo primero que debes hacer es lo siguiente donde te coloque el comentario aqui debes colocar el nombre de seguidor luego separado por barras invertidas colocar el nombre del servidor, es decir te quedaria asi

```
"Data Source=TEST\\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=GPIND;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
```